# How to quantify my experience as a designer on my résumé?

Tags: work, hiring

I am a graphic designer, and I worked in France in two companies for eight years, before I have the eight years experience I worked before as a freelance graphic designer for three years.

Now, my questions:

- I just moved to United States and am confused about what I put on my résumé exactly. Do they count eight years and three years freelancing, which is eleven years as experience, or do they only count on-site experience working with companies?
- Secondly, let's say they don't count freelancing period! which I have eight years of experience on site with companies. Do I call myselfa senior graphic designer or mid-level graphic designer on my résumé? Some people they told me I have seniority, but I don't want to apply on senior positions because am still not confident with my English, and I also have a French accent.

Comment: "Senior" often denotes someone managing a team of "junior" designers - or one who acts as an art director in some respect. It's *rarely* about the time you've worked. And freelancing is pretty much *always* assumed, so it is not really seen as "employment".

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather subjective, and I would say there's no right or wrong answer here. However, for what it's worth, here's my opinion:

I don't think you need to put "mid-level" or "senior" on a CV. If it were me, I wouldn't mention it. Your level of experience should be obvious if you list your employment history, and when you show them your portfolio.

I also don't see any reason why 3 years spent freelancing wouldn't be counted as experience. Just list the time periods you spent working for companies and working freelance. Let the person who's recruiting you make up their own mind about how experienced you are.

Also, there's not much wrong with your English - it's understandable. I've seen much worse here!  By the way, even native English speakers have accents of some sort or another.